# Color contrast using relativ luminance, where does the 0.05 come from

Tags: colors, wcag, high-contrast, luminance

I am currently calculating the contrast of two foreground colors and a background color to programmatically decide if the foreground color should be white or black.

The formula for the contrast ratio is defined as

> (L1 + 0.05) / (L2 + 0.05)

Where L1 is the relative luminance value of the lighter color and L2 is the relative luminance value of the darker color.
WCAG specifies that the optimal ratio for large text is 4.5:1 and for normal text 7:1.

**I can't find an explanation as to why both values need to be incremented by 0.05...**
**Is it simply used to prevent dividing by 0 as the relative luminance for black is exactly 0?**

Here are three reference sources:

1. https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/#contrast-ratio (search for '0.05' using CTRL + F)
2. https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/knowledge/colours-and-contrast/how-to-calculate/#the-formula
3. https://planetcalc.com/7779/

---

Additionally, here is some code, have fun:

```cs
private static readonly Func<Color, double> CalcRelativeLuma = (c) =>
{
    // Convert 8-Bit RGB to sRGB.
    double R = c.R / 255.0;
    double G = c.G / 255.0;
    double B = c.B / 255.0;
    
    // Calculate relative luminance for sRGB values.
    R = R <= 0.03928 ? R / 12.92 : Math.Pow(((R + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4);
    G = G <= 0.03928 ? G / 12.92 : Math.Pow(((G + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4);
    B = B <= 0.03928 ? B / 12.92 : Math.Pow(((B + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4);

    return 0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B;         
};


private Color GetHighContrastColor(Color background)
{
    // Calculate relative luminance of background.
    double l1 = CalcRelativeLuma(background) + 0.05;
    
    // Set contrast colors and calculate relative 
    // luminance of them.
    Color darkContrast = Color.FromArgb(36, 36, 36);
    Color lightContrast = Color.FromArgb(239, 239, 239);
    double l2 = CalcRelativeLuma(darkContrast) + 0.05;
    double l3 = CalcRelativeLuma(lightContrast) + 0.05;
    
    // Calculate contrast ratio for dark and light contrast
    // in regards to the background color.
    double ratio_dark = Math.Max(l1, l2) / Math.Min(l1, l2);
    double ratio_light = Math.Max(l1, l3) / Math.Min(l1, l3);
    
    // Choose which of the contrast colors to use.
    double highContrastRation = Math.Max(ratio_dark, ratio_light);
    Color contrast = Color.Transparent;
    if (highContrastRation == ratio_dark) {
        contrast = darkContrast;
    }
    else {
        contrast = lightContrast;
    }
    return contrast;
}
```

Comment: That's more of a "curiosity" question and not a programming question so is probably not appropriate for stackoverflow. But I found it funny that you were wondering about the 0.05 in the simple contrast formula but didn't ask why dividing each RGB value by 255 then checks against 0.03928. Or why the ratios of 21% for red, 71% for green, and 7% for blue. Or why you take each RGB value and add 0.055 then divide by 1.055 and then raise that to the power of 2.4.

Comment: @slugolicious Dividing the 8-bit RGB values by 255 linearizes them and converts them to sRGB which has a range of 0 to 1. The 0.03928 stems from an exponential curve from the conversion of XYZ to sRGB. The slope of 1/12.92 is roughly 0.03928. Those two values are used when computing the transfer function. The value 0.055 (A) and the exponent 2.4 (Gamma) are used so the curve closely represents a gamma-2.2 curve, which in return gives us 0.03928 for X and 12.9232 for Phi which can be used to describe sRGB conversion.

Comment: @slugolicious The part `Math.Pow(((R + 0.055) / 1.055), 2.4)` is a quantization as the instantaneous gamma varies from 1 in the linear section to 2.4 at the maximum intensity. The values of 0.2126, 0.7152 and 0.0722 are the results of the luminous efficiency function for the XYZ color space. Other color spaces use different values. The YIQ color space uses 0.299, 0.587 and 0.114 for example.

Comment: Most people ask about the entire formula and I was just wondering why you asked about the final calculation. A simple "I already understand the rest of the formula" answer was all that was needed, but your details will probably help someone in the future. I already understand the formula. This was also just a "heads up" that a moderator might consider your question a non-programming question and off topic for stackoverflow. I think it's an interesting topic but perhaps post to https://webaim.org/discussion/

Comment: @slugolicious Thanks for the link! You are right, this is off-topic. I'll try the page you provided

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

The 0.05 addition was intended to represent the flare on the face of the monitor from ambient illumination that was typical of CRT type displays, this flare value is recited in Annex D of the sRGB standard for **Typical Viewing Conditions**.

## Longer Answer

I discuss some of the history in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/w3c/wcag/issues/1705#issuecomment-1027058976), which includes some discussion with one of the members involved at the time WCAG 2.0 was developed. To be sure, the guideline was well meaning, but nevertheless a misstep in terms of useful or stable design guidance.

Unfortunately, just adding the CRT flare value to both sides of the formula doesn't actually correct the problem with using a simple contrast ratio in terms of its lack of perceptual uniformity, so the WCAG 2.x algorithm really only works when the background is very light or white.

Otherwise, it's relatively meaningless, with brute-forced thresholds, and a source of great misunderstanding and controversy.

The WCAG 2.x contrast math and method references an obsolete standard from 1988 that was centered on monochrome CRT matrix-type displays (pixel on or off only). Remember those old green/black displays?

To say that that ancient technology guideline is not relevant to graphically rich full color content on modern LCD or OLED displays is an understatement. I've written some articles on the topic of how and why the guideline is wrong, and ways to improve actual accessibility, including [*"Better reading on the web"*](https://uxdesign.cc/better-reading-on-the-web-c943c4cfc91a), [*"Please Stop Using Grey Text"*](https://tangledweb.xyz/please-stop-using-grey-text-3d3e71acfca8), and [*"A Contrast of Errors"*](https://tangledweb.xyz/a-contrast-of-errors-373c2665d42a).

#### Can it be fixed?

There have been attempts to create better models, one attempt by making the math more like the original Weber, and adding the 0.05 to only one side of the equation (Huang/Peli), but this still does not correct the actual, functional problem: Ratios vs Perceptual Uniformity.

Ratios are not the best way to model human perception of high spatial frequency text contrast at supra-threshold levels on a self-illuminated display. Most especially for rich content on a color display. There is more at work than a simple distance between two colors.

And let's remember that *color* is not a real, "absolute" physical quantity that can be measured per se. Color and contrast are ***perceptions*** of the human vision system. They are context-sensitive and can be modeled. But context sensitive perceptions can not be measured in an absolute sense.

My favorite example that demonstrates this premise is the following checkerboard with a shadow on it. Both yellow dots are emitting the exact same CSS color from your display. Yet the one under the shadow is perceived as brighter because of the context.

[image: a checkerboard with a shadow on it, and two yellow dots, one in shadow and one not. The one in shadow looks brighter]

Context needs to be considered whenever we are attempting to estimate or predict how some given stimulus will appear.

#### Power-curves to the Rescue

In the 1960s, Stevens showed that our perceptions of light changes tend to follow power curves. Stevens also showed that those curves are different based on the spatial frequency (size/thickness of details), and we have found this helps define the perception of text, especially body text, which is at a high spatial frequency.

And since the 1960s, much work has been done in developing perceptually uniform models of color appearance. These newer models have led to substantially more accurate methods of determining contrast for text, and non-text for that matter.

If you'd like to do a deeper dive, please see the article [*"The Realities And Myths Of Contrast And Color"*](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2022/09/realities-myths-contrast-color/). And for an example of a contrast method that uses a more comprehensive model of contrast perception, read the [*"Easy Intro to APCA"*](https://git.apcacontrast.com/documentation/APCAeasyIntro) or see the calculator at  [***apcacontrast.com***](https://apcacontrast.com).

*(Full disclosure, I am the creator of the APCA algorithm, as part of my work as an invited expert of the W3C/WAI and Director of Research for the non-profit [IRT](https://readtech.org/ARC/). Any opinions expressed herein are mine and do not necessarily reflect the views of the W3C or its membership).*